# I used database ID as object key, but I'm getting an error to get the value of that key

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

my objects are saved like this {"5ec801f6c7efb501a06b167f":"hi"} in DB, with userID as key.

```
 return <div>{b.5ec801f6c7efb501a06b167f}</div>;
```

In this line it's showing an error, because the key starts with an integer.
How to solve this?

Comment: Try as `b['5ec801f6c7efb501a06b167f']` instead.

Comment: thank you, it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any java script object property should not start with digits. That's why you are facing issue.

if you need value with that id in `b` use `<div>{b['5ec801f6c7efb501a06b167f']}</div>`.